# if/else statement output not displaying correct message because of plus or minus sign

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have an assignment where we have to present letter grades. The data types without the plus or minus will not put out the correct value. Value 'A' outputs correctly but 'A-' does not. The code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char letGrade;
    cout << "What is your letter grade? ";
    cin >> letGrade;

    if (letGrade == 'A')
        cout << "The numeric value is 4.0\n";

    else if (letGrade == 'A-')
        cout << "The numeric value is 3.5\n";

    cout << "That's an invalid numeric value.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how you expect two characters, an 'A', and a '-', to end up in a single, lonely, `char`? Sorry. You can only put one character in there.

Comment: When I use int, the value doesn't pop up correctly!

Comment: How are you compiling your program?  You should have gotten a warning on that as a "multicharacter constant".  Be sure to pay attention to all compiler output, and it helps to turn the warnings up...if using gcc or clang, add `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` to your command line.  This turns on a lot of warnings and the `-Werror` means it will treat those warnings as errors, so you have to deal with them...always look into the warnings (or ask a question about them) instead of ignoring them!

Answer (score 3):

In the input is `A-`, the line

```
cin >> letGrade;
```

will not read the `-` part to `letGrade`. It will read just the `A` part.

Change `letGrade` to a `std::string`. Also, change the comparison statements to strings.

```
std::string letGrade;
cout << "What is your letter grade? ";
cin >> letGrade;

if (letGrade == "A")
    cout << "The numeric value is 4.0\n";

else if (letGrade == "A-")
    cout << "The numeric value is 3.5\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getLine(string)` to read a `string` because "A-" has TWO characters. Remember that `char` only can hold ONE character, you could use a `char` array but a `string` is more simple. This is an example using `getLine`.

1. `istream& getline (istream& is, string& str, char delim);`
2. `istream& getline (istream& is, string& str);`

`GetLine` extracts characters from `is` and stores them into `str` until the delimitation character `delim` is found (or the newline character, '\n', for (2)).

```
// extract to string
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main ()
{
    std::string name;

    std::cout << "Please, enter your full name: ";
    std::getline (std::cin,name);
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

So, your code will be:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string letGrade;
    cout << "What is your letter grade? ";
    std::getline (std::cin,letGrade);

    if (letGrade == "A")
        cout << "The numeric value is 4.0\n";

    else if (letGrade == "A-")
        cout << "The numeric value is 3.5\n";
    else
        cout << "That's an invalid numeric value.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Only add the needed `else if`. Test it!

Comment: I like this answer. `std::getline` is a much better approach than `cin >>`.